# Sort paragraphs in text file from bash

Tags: bash, sorting

The `sort` utility let's you conveniently sort lines in a file. However, is there an elegant way to sort blank-line separated paragraphs in bash?

For example

```
ccc
aa

aba
bbb

aba
ccc

aaa
```

would have to become

```
aaa

aba
bbb

aba
ccc

ccc
aa
```

One solution seems to be to replace new line symbol on all non-blank lines:

```
ccc\naa    
aba\nbbb
aba\nccc
aaa
```

then call run `sort`

```
aaa
aba\nbbb
aba\nccc
ccc\naa
```

and then restore new lines:

```
aaa

aba
bbb

aba
ccc

ccc
aa
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you're OK with the 'sort' utility, but not the 'sed' utility? I don't really see the distinction. Which other utilities are you OK with and not OK with?

Comment: Also -- does your system's 'sort' support using \0 instead of \n as a delimiter?

Comment: @ruakh I will edit the question. I am actually fine with `sed` solution if you have one.

Comment: @ruakh yes my `sort` supports --zero-terminated argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl to the rescue;

```
perl -n00 -e 'push @a, $_; END { print sort @a }' file
```

The `-00` option enables "paragraph mode" which splits input on empty lines.

If - as in your sample - the last input line isn't necessarily empty, you will need to add a newline separately.

```
perl -n00 -e 'push @a, $_;
   END { $a[-1] .= "\n" if $a[-1] !~ /\n\n$/;
        print sort @a }' file
```

Comment: I liked this very much in the first place. But are you sure that the newlines in the paragraphs (between the fields) will not break the sorting?

Comment: Thinking of it, it depends on the use case. Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: It's a simple lexical sort. The newlines are at the end.  If the final paragraph lacks a separator after it, you will need to adapt the output slightly (with the OP's input, I get `aaa` immediately adjacent to `aba bbb` so it looks like they are a single record).

Comment: Probably I was thinking too complicated. I like the solution, let's see if it works :) (It looks like, you are right)

Answer (score 2):

Put null bytes on the empty lines (and one more at the start), use `sort -z`, then delete the null bytes.  You end up with an extra newline at the start, which you can get rid of with `tail`.

Using `echo` + `sed`:

```
(echo '\0'; cat myfile) |
    sed 's/^$/\x0/' |
    sort -z |
    tr -d '\000' |
    tail -n+2
```

Or, using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "\0"}
    /^$/{printf "\0"} {print $0}' myfile |
sort -z |
tr -d '\000' |
tail -n+2
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's not perfect, but it worked for your input.

```
#!/bin/bash

par=""
while read line
do
   if [ "${#line}" -gt 0 ]; then 
 read -d '' par <<EOF
$par
$line
EOF

   fi
   if [ "${#line}" -eq 0 ]; then
     sort <<< "$par"
     par=""
     echo       
   fi
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

Comment: Maybe it should be pointed out that `while read` in Bash is very inefficient. Also, you really want `read -r` here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a non printable char for the separator symbol. Let's say `\1`.

---

You can use `awk` to translate the file, then sort it, and then use `awk` to translate it back:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS='' OFS='\1' file \
  | sort -i \
  | awk '{$1=$1}1' FS='\1' OFS='\n' ORS='\n\n'
```

`$1=$1` is a no op operation but it still tells awk to reassemble the record using OFS and/or ORS delimiters. All the logic is expressed using that delimiters:

*First awk command*:

- `RS=''` is a special value of the record separator. If `RS` is an empty string, it defaults to two ore more subsequent new lines, which effectively splits by paragraphs. Fields are delimited by new line in this case.
- `OFS='\1'` separates fields by `\1` in the output. The output record separator defaults to one newline.

This gives us:

```
ccc<garbage>aa
aba<garbage>bbb
aba<garbage>ccc
aaa
```

We can now `sort -i` that. `-i` ignores non printable characters, this gives us:

```
aaa
aba<garbage>bbb
aba<garbage>ccc
ccc<garbage>aa
```

*The second awk command*

- `FS='\1'` splits input fields by `\1`
- `OFS='\n'` sets the output field delimiter to newline
- `ORS='\n\n'` sets the output record delimiter to two newlines, which is effectively an empty line.

Output:

```
aaa

aba
bbb

aba
ccc

ccc
aa
```

---

Note that this solution will not preserve more than a single newline between paragraphs.